# Postgres Fulltext Query Very Slow (GIN Index, 3 Million Rows)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

USING A SIMPLE FULLTEXT QUERY:

I used only the column which is indexed in the SELECT to avoid additional disk reads.

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT products_vector
FROM products
WHERE
products_vector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'sulfuric | acid | 0.1n');
```

RESULT:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=2190.65..295693.90 rows=116987 width=148) (actual time=715.964..315781.144 rows=111681 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (products_vector @@ '''sulfuric'' | ''acid'' | ''0.1'' & ''n'''::tsquery)
   Heap Blocks: exact=84740
   Buffers: shared hit=6 read=85492
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_fulltext_search  (cost=0.00..2161.40 rows=116987 width=0) (actual time=643.421..643.428 rows=112306 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (products_vector @@ '''sulfuric'' | ''acid'' | ''0.1'' & ''n'''::tsquery)
         Buffers: shared hit=6 read=322
 Planning Time: 808.165 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 4
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.253 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 2.188 ms, Emission 24.550 ms, Total 28.991 ms
 Execution Time: 316028.302 ms
(13 rows)
```

LIMITING THE NUMBER OF ROWS FETCHED (but ranking is added):

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        ts_rank(products_vector, to_tsquery('simple', 'sulfuric | acid | 0.1n')  ) as score
    FROM products
    WHERE
        products_vector @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'sulfuric | acid | 0.1n')
) as t1
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

RESULT:

```
Limit  (cost=299099.35..299099.40 rows=20 width=8) (actual time=755802.185..755802.190 rows=20 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=364399 read=140370
   ->  Sort  (cost=299099.35..299391.82 rows=116987 width=8) (actual time=755248.597..755248.600 rows=20 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (ts_rank(products.products_vector, '''sulfuric'' | ''acid'' | ''0.1'' & ''n'''::tsquery)) DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
         Buffers: shared hit=364399 read=140370
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products  (cost=2190.65..295986.37 rows=116987 width=8) (actual time=1144.787..755097.254 rows=111681 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (products_vector @@ '''sulfuric'' | ''acid'' | ''0.1'' & ''n'''::tsquery)
               Heap Blocks: exact=84740
               Buffers: shared hit=364396 read=140370
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_fulltext_search  (cost=0.00..2161.40 rows=116987 width=0) (actual time=956.063..956.064 rows=112306 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (products_vector @@ '''sulfuric'' | ''acid'' | ''0.1'' & ''n'''::tsquery)
                     Buffers: shared hit=6 read=322
 Planning Time: 728.459 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 6
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.352 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 184.210 ms, Emission 358.190 ms, Total 544.751 ms
 Execution Time: 757308.337 ms
```

I can notice that a large number of rows are being read, but i do not have an option but to read them in these cases.

Even a query using to_tsquery('simple', 'sulfuric & acid & 0.1n') is taking over a minute to execute.

My Questions are:

1. How do i make these queries faster?
2. Is "Bitmap Heap Scan" slow because of bad settings? In that case how do i identify those?
3. I tried to eliminate "Bitmap Heap Scan" by not selecting any other column except product_vector in the first query? How is it still slow?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

> I used only the column which is indexed in the SELECT to avoid additional disk reads.

This doesn't work with a GIN index, as each column value is broken apart and spread over many index rows.  You can't reassemble the original value from the index entries, you have to visit the table to get the original value.

What happens if you don't even select the indexed column, e.g. `count(*)`?  If you execute the value repeatedly back to back, what is the timing on repeat execution?  What plans do you get if you turn `track_io_timing` on?

> but i do not have an option but to read them in these cases.

Why not?

> Even a query using to_tsquery('simple', 'sulfuric & acid & 0.1n') is taking over a minute to execute.

What is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` (with `track_io_timing` turned on) for that one?